# Parsing a String to a Date

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee, date

I have a String `2012-10-23` which I need to convert into a Date object.

Can I pass this string directly to the below function

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
```

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd` would be correct

Comment: Have you read the javadoc for SimpleDateFormat before asking? If so, why don't you follow the clear explanation in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
```

for `2012-10-23` your format should be `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

Comment: why my answer has been closed

Comment: @PSR: You should add a little explanation to your answer. Maybe it will be undeleted then.

Comment: @PSR, because by the time you edited out the mistake, there were new answers, and your answer stand duplicate. I have casted my undelete vote, but it will require 3 undelete votes. Your original answer seemed like [Fastest Gun in West problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Answer (score 2):

```
String string = "2012-10-23";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);


Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
G   Era designator  Text    AD
y   Year    Year    1996; 96
Y   Week year   Year    2009; 09
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
w   Week in year    Number  27
W   Week in month   Number  2
D   Day in year Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
F   Day of week in month    Number  2
E   Day name in week    Text    Tuesday; Tue
u   Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)    Number  1
a   Am/pm marker    Text    PM
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
m   Minute in hour  Number  30
s   Second in minute    Number  55
S   Millisecond Number  978
z   Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
X   Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00
```

Comment: sorry by mistake i did that

Comment: Because the format is wrong

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, this is how

```
String string = "2012-10-23";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(string);
```